# An adjective to describe the nature of information used to blackmail someone

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

In [yesterday's Washington Examiner article](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/congress/democrats-say-putin-has-kompromat-on-trump-gop-says-no-way), the word "kompromat" was used to describe a piece of "compromising information" Russia might have on Trump.

What I'm looking for is a less vague synonym to "compromising", a word you'd use to describe an information which would make a person look bad in other people's eyes. Not necessarily in a criminal way, so "incriminating" would be too strong and off-topic - more like in a general way, but still less formal and flat than "compromising".

Any ideas?

PS: I'm asking since I strongly believe I had seen an exact word I'm now looking for before - but now I just cannot recall it.

Comment: demonizing, denigrating, probably?

Comment: Give us an example sentence how you would use the word. To help us help you.

Comment: @CowperKettle You don't seem to have got the point, though.

Comment: Perhaps damning?

Comment: @CowperKettle, "denigrating" seems quite relevant, although I don't think it was the word I used to know but now forgot. Would accept that as an answer if you posted it as one.

Comment: Please, why are you not working your way through dictionaries and thesauruses… the more so since this seems to have started in Russian, not English?

Comment: [Scandalous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scandalous) information?

Comment: We don't say "an information" in English. The slang term is "dirt".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the term that you may be looking for is ***undermining***.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/undermine) provides a learner's definition of *undermine* and some examples:

> If you *undermine* someone or undermine their position or authority, you make their authority or position less secure, often by indirect methods.
>
> **examples**
>
> *She undermined him and destroyed his confidence in his own talent. [VERB noun]*
>
> *The conversations were designed to undermine her authority. [VERB noun]*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

X had some ***unsavoury/unsavory*** information about Y.

ODO:

> **[unsavoury](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unsavoury)** (*US* unsavory)
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Disagreeable and unpleasant because morally disreputable.
>   ‘an unsavoury reputation’

In usage:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unsavoury+information%22
>   https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unsavory+information%22

Also, ***unflattering***.

X had some ***unflattering*** information about Y.

Cambridge:

> **[unflattering](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unflattering)**
>   *adjective* UK, US
>   making someone look less attractive or seem worse than usual:
>
> The book portrays her in a very unflattering light.

In Usage:

> https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unflattering+information%22&oq=%22unflattering+information%22